# Powershell command to List the services on a specific/individual cluster node

Tags: powershell

How to find the list of service on a specific node in a given cluster using Powershell?

There are 2 nodes in this cluster group `ServerName_1` and `ServerName_2`, I am trying to fetch the services on `Server_name1`.

I have tried running the below commands but I did not get any output or error.

I tried using the below command and I could get the results:

```
PS C:\Users\sd> Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.State -EQ "Online"}

Name                    OwnerNode           State
----                    ---------           -----  
Service_1              ServerName_1       Online  
Service_2              ServerName_2       Online
```

However, when i tried to extract the OwnerNode using the same command i do not see any result , as observed below:

```
PS C:\Users\sd> Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.OwnerNode -EQ <ServerName_1>}
PS C:\Users\sd>
```

As I do not see any output, I am not sure whether the command i executed is correct?

I need this, so that I may start the specific service on ServerName_1 alone.

```
PS C:\Users\sd> Start-ClusterGroup -Name <ServiceName> | Where-Object
 { $_.OwnerNode -eq "<ServerName1>" }

PS C:\Users\sd>
```

Comment: Do you actually have it as `-eq <ServerName_1>`? If so, you need to put the server name in quotes `"ServerName_1"`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `< >` in your code, update

```
Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.OwnerNode -EQ <ServerName_1>}
```

to

```
Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.OwnerNode -EQ "ServerName_1"}
```

Comment: Please pardon if ServerName_1 is causing confusion. I have used it only for representational pruposes. There is a definite server name which i put inside the quotes " ".

Comment: So you added `< >` only to represent a server name in your example? This breaks the code and doesn't help us find your problem. It's better to *only* change the server name and not change any other text eg `{$_.OwnerNode -EQ "MySecretServer_1"}` is updated to `{$_.OwnerNode -EQ "ServerName_1"}`, I would recommend going back to your question and updating it so you've not added anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works as expected:

List the ClusterGrop Names-

```
Get-ClusterNode -Name "Server_name" | Get-ClusterGroup
```

Also,
List the ClusterGroup Services -

```
Get-ClusterNode -Name "Server_name" | Get-ClusterResource
```